# Angular2 and Angularfire nested *ngfor issues

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, nested-loops, angularfire2, ngfor

Component

```
export class Component{
  people: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public af:AngularFire) {
    this.people = af.database.list('/people')
    .map((people) => {  
      return people.map((person) => {    
        person.post = af.database.list(`/post/${person.$key}`)
        .map((comments) => {
          return comments.map ((comment) => {
            person.post.comment = af.database.list(`/comments/${comment.$key}`)
            return person.post
          })
        })
        return person
      })    
    });
  }
}
```

Html

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let person of people | async">
    {{ person.name }}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let todo of person.post | async">
        {{todo.name}}        
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let comment of person.post.comment | async">
                    {{comment.name}} 

                </li>
                <li>
                    <form (submit)="person.post.comment.push({ name:form3.value})">
                        <input #form3><label for="form3">Add Person.post.Comment</label> 
                    </form> 
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li>             
        <form (submit)="person.post.push({ name:form2.value})">
            <input #form2><label for="form2">Add Person.post</label>
        </form>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <form (submit)="people.push({ name:form1.value})">
        <input #form1><label for="form1">Add Person</label> 
    </form> 
</li>
```

I'm trying to have the following:

Create people.
for each person a post can be created
for each post a comment can be created.

---

I  can get it working with just going people and post. But adding on the comment layer isn't.

It is creating them the way I want correctly in the firebase database. But on the read from firebase I am getting the follow problems.

---

Can't read the post layer (get the bullet point but not the object)

Can read the comment layer but it puts the comments across all the posts under the person heading.

Comment: What else can't you do?

Comment: If I add the json pipe I get a circular error

Comment: Surprising error? Does you object have circular dependencies?